# ¿Alguien me puede explicar bien JSON y como utilizarlo para refrescar la información he probado con ajax pero no lo entiendo?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hola buenas la variable de reservas tiene guardas las horas que están en la base de datos y necesito mostrarlas en el párrafo del id horasDb. El problema es el siguiente tengo un Calendario con Jquery y necesito comparar las horas que tengo guardas en la base de datos y las que hay libres para bloquearlas...
El problema es que no me refresca el parrafo de id horasDb hasta que no se le da por segunda vez a elegir la fecha......
Haber si alguien me puede ayudar a refrescar la informacion  me han comentado que hay que utilizar ajax  para eso pero estoy perdido alguna ayuda porfavor
De ajax he probado eso y no me funciona..

```
$("#enviar").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "reservar1.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $($reservas).serialize(),
    success: function(horasDb) {
      $("#horasDb").html(horasDb);
    }
  });
});

     <?php
           $fechacliente=$_POST["fechacliente"];
           $consultahora = "SELECT date_format(hora,'%H:%i') as 'hora' from reservas 
            where fechareserva=str_to_date('".$fechacliente."','%d/%m/%Y') and idpeluqueros=1;";
           $resultado1 = $conexion->prepare($consultahora);
           $resultado1->execute();
           $horas=$resultado1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                
                 $reservas=[];
                 foreach($horas as $hora){
                                                    
                    array_push($reservas,$hora["hora"]);
                                                     
                   }
    ?>
        $(function() {
        
        const dias_semana = {
          0: 0,1: 1,2: 2,3: 3,4: 4,5: 5,6: 6
        }
        
        $("#fecha").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            onSelect: function(dia_semm) {
              const [day, month, year] = dia_semm.split('/');
              const date = new Date(year, (month - 1), day);
              const num_dia_sem = date.getDay();
             
              var horasDb = JSON.parse(`<?php echo json_encode($reservas); ?>`);        
              document.getElementById("horasDb").innerHTML = horasDb;    
         
        
              if((dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==1){
                var dia= new Array();
                var barra_horas = '';
                dia=horaslune();
                var long = dia.length;
                // alert(long);
                for(i=0;i<long;i++)
                {   
                     barra_horas = barra_horas+dia[i] ;
                }
                document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML = barra_horas;
              }
              if((dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==6){
                var dias= new Array();
                var barra_horas = '';
                dias=horassabad();
                var long = dias.length;
                // alert(long);
                for(i=0;i<long;i++)
                {   
                     barra_horas = barra_horas+dias[i] ;
                }
                document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML = barra_horas;
        
              }
              if((dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==2 || (dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==3 || (dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==4 || (dias_semana[num_dia_sem])==5 ){
                var diass= new Array();
                var barra_horas = '';
                diass=horas();
                var long = diass.length;
                // alert(long);
                for(i=0;i<long;i++)
                {   
                     barra_horas = barra_horas+diass[i] ;
                }
                document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML = barra_horas;
              }
              
            },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
                   minDate: today,
                   maxDate: end_day,
            //  beforeShowDay: my_check,
                   beforeShowDay: my_check
        
          });
        });
      
            <form id="formulario" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
                    <fieldset >
                        <div >
                        <label >Fecha:</label>
                    <div ><input type="text" value="" id="fecha" name="fechacliente" size="20"/ 
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                  <input type="burron" id="enviar"  value="Comprobar horas disponibles" />
                        <div >       
            </form>
             <p id="horasDb"> </p>
```

Comment: Busca jquery ajax y veras cientos de ejemplo.. si sabes que necesitas no es mejor idea investigar antes de preguntar?

Comment: Ya estado investigando un montón pero estoy perdido en ajax yo es que soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y otras cosas si las he podido sacar pero esto no puedo sacarlo

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta y colocar lo que as intentado con ajax y si no entiendes ajax es pedir una explicacion detallada en base a tu ajax

Comment: Ya lo he modificado puff llevo bastante tiempo intentándolo encontrar una solución cada vez me desquicia mas...

Comment: separa tu codigo en diferentes scripts de PHP, JS y HTML, por eso se te dificulta tanto encontrar el error, es muy difícil leer el código de esa manera, como observación, para que una petición Ajax obtenga la data de PHP tienes que hacer un **echo** ejemplo: **echo $reservas;**, de lo contrario Ajax no obtendrá respuesta, o también en forma de JSON.

Comment: Si en forma de JSON lo tengo me lo envia pero no refresca

Comment: Pero eso no es el problema que necesito sincronizar los datos con ajax y quisiera saber eso